# How to decode this Ajax response in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

How do I decode the following response from this url in python?  https://www.scorespro.com/livescore/ajax0.php

```
1599071734^^~~@@Wed 02 Sep 21:35 GMT +03^^~~@@2361498-1##194837##0##2020-09-02 17:00:00##76##1##18032##17842##Club Friendly##0##Real Sociedad##Villarreal##CLB##un##FG##0-2##0-2##2 HF##Friendly Games##1599066000######2##99######real-sociedad-vs-villarreal/02-09-2020##friendly-games##club-friendly##2##LEAGUE##2020##round-1##0####0##1599066240##############0##0 2325164-1##196097##0##2020-09-02 17:00:00##71##1##105187##104946##Canadian Premier League - Premier League##0##Valour FC (5)##HFX Wanderers FC (6)##PL##ca##CAN##0-2##0-2##2 HF##Canada##1599066000######2##99######valour-fc-vs-hfx-wanderers-fc/30-05-2020##canada##premier-league##1##LEAGUE##2020##round-1##1##canadian-premier-league##0##1599066540##############0##0 2338959-1##197065##0##2020-09-02 17:00:00##81##4##39942##41961##Regionalliga Nordost##0##Germania Halberstadt (18)##Optik Rathenow (20)##N/E##de##GER##0-2##0-0##2 HF##Germany##1599066000######2##99######germania-halberstadt-vs-optik-rathenow/02-09-2020##germany##regionalliga-nordost##5##LEAGUE##2020-2021##round-4##1####0##1599065940##############0##0 2338955-1##197065##0##2020-09-02 17:00:00##81##4##44124##56097##Regionalliga Nordost##0##Viktoria Berlin (2)##VSG Altglienicke (1)##N/E##de##GER##2-1##1-1##2 HF##Germany##1599066000######2##99######viktoria-berlin-vs-vsg-altglienicke/02-09-2020##germany##regionalliga-nordost##5##LEAGUE##2020-2021##round-4##1####0##1599065940##############0##0 2338958-1##197065##0##2020-09-02 17:00:00##78##4##13847##3034##Regionalliga Nordost##0##SV Babelsberg 03 (12)##Chemnitzer FC (15)##N/E##de##GER##2-2##1-1##2 HF##Germany##1599066000######2##99######sv-babelsberg-03-vs-chemnitzer-fc/02-09-2020##germany##regionalliga-nordost##5##LEAGUE##2020-2021##round-4##1####0##1599066120##############0##0 2338954-1##197065##0##2020-09-02 17:00:00##79##4##21173##37508##Regionalliga Nordost##0##Hertha Berlin II (5)##Berliner AK 07 (16)##N/E##de##GER##2-5##1-2##2 HF##Germany##1599066000######2##99######hertha-berlin-ii-vs-berliner-ak-07/02-09-2020##germany##regionalliga-nordost##5##LEAGUE##2020-2021##round-4##1####0##1599066060##############0##0 2361307-1##197664##0##2020-09-02 17:00:00##81##1##24981##21152##Landspokal##0##Slagelse##Dalum##CUP##dk##DEN##1-1##0-0##2 HF##Denmark##1599066000######2##99######slagelse-vs-dalum/01-09-2020##denmark##fa-cup##6##PHASE##2020-2021##round-1##0####0##1599065940##2.20##2.87##3.75########0##0 2338953-1##197065##0##2020-09-02 17:00:00##80##4##41959##2993##Regionalliga Nordost##0##VfB Auerbach (7)##Energie Cottbus (19)##N/E##de##GER##2-4##1-2##2 HF##Germany##1599066000######2##99######vfb-auerbach-vs-energie-cottbus/02-09-2020##germany##regionalliga-nordost##5##LEAGUE##2020-2021##round-4##1####0##1599066000##############0##0 2307988-1##195163##0##2020-09-02 17:15:00##62##10##34050##49891##Serie A - First Stage##0##CD Olmedo (16)##Delfin SC (10)##SA1##ec##ECU##2-0##2-0##2 HF##Ecuador##1599066900######2##99######cd-olmedo-vs-delfin-sc/10-05-2020##ecuador##first-stage##1##LEAGUE##2020##round-10##1##serie-a##0##1599067080##2.45##2.55##3.25########1##1 2338956-1##197065##0##2020-09-02 17:30:00##HT##4##41960##50882##Regionalliga Nordost##0##Lokomotive Leipzig (13)##FSV 63 Luckenwalde (8)##N/E##de##GER##1-0##1-0##H/T##Germany##1599067800######2##99######lokomotive-leipzig-vs-fsv-63-luckenwalde/02-09-2020##germany##regionalliga-nordost##5##LEAGUE##2020-2021##round-4##1####0##0##############0##0 2367153-1##194837##0##2020-09-02 17:30:00##HT##1##18022##4189##Club Friendly##0##Real Betis##Almeria##CLB##un##FG##1-0##1-0##H/T##Friendly Games##1599067800######2##99######real-betis-vs-almeria/02-09-2020##friendly-games##club-friendly##2##LEAGUE##2020##round-1##0####0##0##1.53##6.00##3.50########0##0 2313051-1##195400##0##2020-09-02 17:30:00##48##15##43773##103469##1. Deild##0##Magni (12)##Afturelding (8)##D2##is##ISL##2-0##2-0##2 HF##Iceland##1599067800######2##99######magni-vs-afturelding/29-07-2020##iceland##1-deild##2##LEAGUE##2020##round-15##1####0##1599067920##############0##0 2366633-1##194837##0##2020-09-02 17:30:00##47##1##18052##28704##Club Friendly##0##Levante##Cartagena##CLB##un##FG##1-1##1-1##2 HF##Friendly Games##1599067800######2##99######levante-vs-cartagena/02-09-2020##friendly-games##club-friendly##2##LEAGUE##2020##round-1##0####0##1599067980##1.40##5.25##4.20########0##1 2313052-1##195400##0##2020-09-02 17:30:00##47##15##52987##30414##1. Deild##0##Vestri (7)##Thor Akureyri (5)##D2##is##ISL##1-0##1-0##2 HF##Iceland##1599067800######2##99######vestri-vs-thor-akureyri/29-07-2020##iceland##1-deild##2##LEAGUE##2020##round-15##1####0##1599067980##############0##0 2313056-1##195400##0##2020-09-02 17:30:00##47##15##26363##32547##1. Deild##0##IBV Vestmannaeyjar (3)##Leiknir R. (4)##D2##is##ISL##0-2##0-2##2 HF##Iceland##1599067800######2##99######ibv-vestmannaeyjar-vs-leiknir-r/01-08-2020##iceland##1-deild##2##LEAGUE##2020##round-15##1####0##1599067980##############0##0 2363441-1##194837##0##2020-09-02 18:00:00##36##1##21281##3220##Club Friendly##0##Benfica##SC Braga##CLB##un##FG##0-0##-##1 HF##Friendly Games##1599069600######2##99######benfica-vs-sc-braga/02-09-2020##friendly-games##club-friendly##2##LEAGUE##2020##round-1##0####0##1599069540##1.55##5.50##3.50########0##0 2289461-1##193678##0##2020-09-02 18:30:00##4##24##40009##40019##Premier League##0##Smouha SC (6)##El Entag El Harby (14)##PL##eg##EGY##0-0##-##1 HF##Egypt##1599071400######2##99######smouha-sc-vs-el-entag-el-harby/02-03-2020##egypt##premier-league##1##LEAGUE##2019-2020##round-24##1####0##1599071460##2.15##4.00##2.70########0##0 2211667-1##190057##0##2020-09-02 18:30:00##1##1##23376##19092##U21 Championship - Qualifying Group Stage##0##San Marino U21 (6)##Czech Republic U21 (1)##QR##eu##UEF##0-0##-##1 HF##Europe (UEFA)##1599071400######2##8######san-marino-u21-vs-czech-republic-u21/02-09-2020##uefa##qualifying-group-stage##8##PHASE##2021-hungary-slovenia##round-1##1##u21-championship##1##1599071640##29.00##1.01##21.00########0##0 ^^@@a##1599071731##1599071658^^~~@@5333322-1##197760##0-1##Set 2##2##40089##32214##Pavic/Soares B.##Granollers-P M./Zeballos H. (5)##US OPEN##us##ATP##3-6|2-2|-|-|-##ATP Doubles##US Open##1599068700####H##atp-doubles##us-open##2020######195167######0####13##R32##3########################Set2##-2##z##1##- 5333324-1##197760##0-1##Set 2##2##41811##51180##Bambridge L./McLachlan B.##Eubanks C./Mcdonald M. (wc)##US OPEN##us##ATP##3-6|2-5|-|-|-##ATP Doubles##US Open##1599067500####A##atp-doubles##us-open##2020######195167######0####16##R32##3########################Set2##-2##z##0##- 5333325-1##197760##1-1##Set 3##2##27573##39167##Chardy J./Martin F.##Harrison C./Harrison R. (wc)##US OPEN##us##ATP##7-5|65-77|0-0|-|-##ATP Doubles##US Open##1599066000####H##atp-doubles##us-open##2020######195167######0####25##R32##3########################Set3##-2##z##1##30-30 5333330-1##197760##1-0##Set 2##2##143786##21596##Gille S./Vliegen J.##Kubot L./Melo M. (2)##US OPEN##us##ATP##6-2|4-3|-|-|-##ATP Doubles##US Open##1599067500####H##atp-doubles##us-open##2020######195167######0####15##R32##3########################Set2##-2##z##1##30-15 5334089-1##197805##1-1##Set 3##2##145891##145017##Carlos Alcaraz (se)##Juan Pablo Ficovich####it##CHM##4-6|6-3|5-4|-|-##Challenger Men Singles##Cordenons (Italy)##1599063000####H##challenger-men-singles##cordenons##2020##es##ar##195223##ESP##ARG######28##R32##5########################Set3##10##z##1##- 5334294-1##197761##0-1##Set 2##2##46027##43093##Gerasimov E.##Thompson J.##US OPEN##us##ATP##1-6|3-5|-|-|-##ATP Singles##US Open##1599067500####H##atp-singles##us-open##2020##by##au##195166##BLR##AUS##0####15##R64##1######gerasimov-e##thompson-j################Set2##-2##z##1##40-30 5334313-1##197761##0-0##Set 1##2##58519##52671##Davidovich Fokina A.##Hurkacz H. (24)##US OPEN##us##ATP##0-0|-|-|-|-##ATP Singles##US Open##1599071700####A##atp-singles##us-open##2020##es##pl##195166##ESP##POL##0####0##R64##1######davidovich-fokina-a##hurkacz-h################Set1##-2##z##1##40-15 5334316-1##197761##0-0##Set 1##2##21374##41813##Djokovic N. (1)##Edmund K.##US OPEN##us##ATP##1-2|-|-|-|-##ATP Singles##US Open##1599070500####H##atp-singles##us-open##2020##rs##gb-eng##195166##SRB##ENG##0####3##R64##1######novak-djokovic##edmund-k################Set1##-2##z##1##- 5334317-1##197761##0-1##Set 2##2##143584##44241##Nakashima B. (wc)##Zverev A. (5)##US OPEN##us##ATP##5-7|4-3|-|-|-##ATP Singles##US Open##1599066600####A##atp-singles##us-open##2020##us##de##195166##USA##GER##0####19##R64##1######nakashima-b##alexander-zverev################Set2##-2##z##1##15-40 5334319-1##197761##0-0##Set 1##2##55929##38842##Harris Ll.##Goffin D. (7)##US OPEN##us##ATP##4-3|-|-|-|-##ATP Singles##US Open##1599069300####A##atp-singles##us-open##2020##za##be##195166##RSA##BEL##0####7##R64##1######harris-ll##david-goffin################Set1##-2##z##1##30-15 5334322-1##197761##0-0##Set 1##2##32375##38073##Mannarino A. (32)##Sock J. (pr)##US OPEN##us##ATP##1-2|-|-|-|-##ATP Singles##US Open##1599070800####H##atp-singles##us-open##2020##fr##us##195166##FRA##USA##0####3##R64##1######adrian-mannarino##jack-sock################Set1##-2##z##1##30-15 5334325-1##197761##2-0##Set 3##2##31424##42596##Kukushkin M.##Garin C. (13)##US OPEN##us##ATP##6-2|6-1|2-5|-|-##ATP Singles##US Open##1599065100####H##atp-singles##us-open##2020##kz##cl##195166##KAZ##CHI##0####22##R64##1######mikhail-kukushkin##garin-c################Set3##-2##z##1##40-15 5334328-1##197761##0-0##Set 1##2##51475##43105##Mmoh M. (wc)##Struff J-L. (28)##US OPEN##us##ATP##2-5|-|-|-|-##ATP Singles##US Open##1599070200####A##atp-singles##us-open##2020##us##de##195166##USA##GER##0####7##R64##1######mmoh-m##jan-lennard-struff################Set1##-2##z##1##- 5334329-1##197763##0-1##Set 2##2##4337##41349##Flipkens K.##Pegula J. (wc)##US##us##WTA##61-77|0-0|-|-|-##WTA Singles##US Open##1599068100####H##wta-singles##us-open##2020##be##us##195168##BEL##USA##0####13##R64##2######kirsten-flipkens##pegula-j################Set2##10##z##1##15-0 ^^@@a##1599071731##0^^~~@@5320202-1##197316##68-62##Q4##2##47955##47954##TBV Start Lublin##Polski Cukier Torun##PLK-RS##pl##POL##21-16|15-15|18-21|14-10| - |36-31##Poland##Energa Basket Liga##1599066000######poland##energa-basket-liga##2020-2021######197315######1####1.21##4.25##########4Qrt##1##z##0 ^^@@a##1599071661##0^^~~@@5333286-3##197776##1-0##Set 2##2##8410##8414##Spor Toto (1)##Ziraat Bankasi (2)##GS##tr##TUR##25-18|8-5|-|-|-##Turkey##Turkish Cup - Group Stage##1599069600######turkey##national-cup##2020-2021######197447######1####56##############2S##3##z##0 ^^@@a##1599071674##1599071126^^~~@@5302817-3##196725##28-21##2H##2##140460##41158##Molde W##Larvik W##RS##no##NOR##13-9##Norway##REMA 1000-ligaen - Women##1599066900######norway##postenligaen-women##2020-2021######196717######1####49##1.12##7.50##12.00########2H##2##z##0 5303101-3##196762##21-13##2H##2##8559##3172##Sonderjyske##Skjern##RS##dk##DEN##16-10##Denmark##Handbold Liagen##1599067800######denmark##handball-league##2020-2021######196756######1####34##3.40##1.55##8.50########2H##1##z##0 5303102-3##196762##1-0##1H##2##3517##3516##Skanderborg##Arhus GF##RS##dk##DEN##1-0##Denmark##Handbold Liagen##1599071400######denmark##handball-league##2020-2021######196756######1##1H##1##1.35##4.50##9.50########1H##1##z##0 5304740-3##196776##25-16##2H##2##3587##6865##Kadetten Schaffhausen##Amicitia Zurich##RS##ch##SUI##10-9##Switzerland##NLA##1599066000######switzerland##nla##2020-2021######196774######1####41##1.11##8.00##12.00########2H##1##z##0 5304741-3##196776##12-11##2H##2##10782##10780##HC Kriens##Wacker Thun##RS##ch##SUI##11-10##Switzerland##NLA##1599067800######switzerland##nla##2020-2021######196774######1##H##23##1.50##3.20##8.00########2H##1##z##0 5304742-3##196776##22-18##2H##2##10786##10783##Pfadi Winterthur##Bern Muri##RS##ch##SUI##19-13##Switzerland##NLA##1599067800######switzerland##nla##2020-2021######196774######1##A##40##1.25##5.00##10.00########2H##1##z##0 5304743-3##196776##15-15##2H##2##10777##10784##St. Otmar St. Gallen##Suhr Aarau##RS##ch##SUI##14-15##Switzerland##NLA##1599067800######switzerland##nla##2020-2021######196774######1####30##2.00##2.15##7.50########2H##1##z##0 5304744-3##196776##7-7##1H##2##12340##10778##Endingen##1879 Basel##RS##ch##SUI##7-7##Switzerland##NLA##1599069600######switzerland##nla##2020-2021######196774######1####14##1.67##2.60##7.50########1H##1##z##0 5312581-3##197132##11-17##HT##2##41099##3282##Oroshazi##Pick Szeged##RS##hu##HUN##11-17##Hungary##Liga 1##1599068700######hungary##liga-1##2020-2021######197130######1####28##67.00##1.00##50.00########H/T##1##z##0 5334268-3##197814##2-3##1H##2##9591##9590##Fivers WAT Margareten##Alpla Hard##CUP##at##AUT##2-3##Austria##Super Cup - Cup##1599070800######austria##super-cup##2020-2021######197234######0##H##5##1.67##2.60##7.50########1H##5##z##0 ^^@@a##1599071731##1599071728^^~~@@5321546-1##197388##2-2##P3##2##22308##22300##HC CSKA Moscow##AK Bars Kazan##KHL-RS##ru##RUS##1-0|0-1|1-1| - | - ##Russia##KHL##1599064200######russia##khl##2020-2021######197387######1####hc-cska-moscow-vs-ak-bars-kazan/02-09-2020##1.67##2.25##########3Per##1##z##1 ^^@@a##1599071289##0^^~~@@^^@@a##1597635989##0^^~~@@^^@@a##1599057728##0^^~~@@^^@@a##0##0^^~~@@^^@@a##1599042879##1590074504^^~~@@^^@@a##1599045851##0^^~~@@^^@@a##1599071265##0^^~~@@45
```

Comment: According to https://www.scorespro.com/livescore-xml/ they have XML and JSON feeds. You should use them instead of this cryptic API.

Comment: You are correct, however they are limited to 10 items per pull.  I need more than 10.

Comment: That doesn't look like any kind of standard data format. You'll need to find the documentation that explains it.